# Написать обертку для работы с хэндлами файлов (аналог auto_ptr но для хэндлов)

Tags: c++, классы

Написал вот такой простой код:

```
class FileHandleGuard
{
private:
    HANDLE hFile;
public:
    FileHandleGuard(char* fileName) {
        hFile = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,  OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  NULL);  
    }
    FileHandleGuard(const FileHandleGuard& other) {
        this->hFile = other.hFile;
    }
    ~FileHandleGuard() {
        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
};

void g(FileHandleGuard f) {
    cout << "g " << endl;
    //вот тут происходит ошибка в деструкторе
}
void someFunction() {
    FileHandleGuard fileHandle("D://myfile.txt");
    g(fileHandle);
}
int main() {
    someFunction();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При передаче в функцию `g` мой умный указатель должен вести себя так же как и `auto_ptr`, т.е. когда передали в функцию - только эта функция владеет объектом
а та функция, которая передала - уже не владеет
На данный момент получаю ошибку: `0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified`.

Исходная постановка задачи написана в заголовке вопроса.
И правильно ли вообще, что я использую Хэндл из библиотеки `windows.h` ?

Comment: Вашему коду явно не хватает счетчика для handle.

Comment: Согласно вашего кода, у вас может быть несколько объектов, которые хранят хендл одного и того же файла. Но если вызовется деструктор хотя бы одного из этих объектов, то во всех остальных он станет не валидным.

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами написали, что при передаче в функцию (читай - копировании) передается владение, так что

```
FileHandleGuard(const FileHandleGuard& other) {
    this->hFile = other.hFile;
}
```

нужно переписать как

```
FileHandleGuard(FileHandleGuard& other) {
    this->hFile = other.hFile;
    other.hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```

Кстати, соответственно нужно написать и оператор присваивания...

Comment: Если вопрос только в передаче в функцию, то оператор присваивания можно просто запретить?..

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну мало ли для чего он может понадобиться?...

Answer (score 0):

Оператор копирования создаёт дубликат. Вам же необходимо передать владение. Так как владение жёстко завязано на объект-контейнер, его необходимо *переместить* (в терминах [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)).

Для реализации возможности перемещения необходимо добавить *конструктор перемещения* и *оператор перемещающего присваивания*.

```
// Мы за безопасное программирование. Поэтому лучше не допускать наличия
// двух копий дескриптора.
FileHandleGuard(FileHandleGuard&& other)
    : hFile(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    std::swap(hFile, other.hFile);
}

FileHandleGuard& operator=(FileHandleGuard&& other) nothrow
{
    // Метод объявлен как nothrow (то есть никто не выбросит исключения 
    // посреди перемещения, оставив объект в «подвешенном» состоянии)
    hFile = other.hFile;
    other.hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```

При этом конструктор и оператор копирования по умолчанию исчезнут, так как ручное объявление хотя бы одного конструктора [отменяет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944131/2553424) автоматическое создание остальных вариантов конструкторов и перегрузок `operator=()`.